# Gmail add-on - any way to hide universal actions?

Tags: gmail, gmail-addons

In Gmail Appscript manifest we can configure universal actions which will show in all the cards. Is there any way to hide those on specific cards.

Ex:- I want to show them only on specific card

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution for this

We can add an action to the card like below which will appear in more option

> CardBuilder.addCardAction(CardService.newCardAction().setText("test").setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("test")));